# Spider-man and the wrestling ring

Tags: spider-man, adaptation-comparison, marvel

In both 2002's Spider-man and 2012's The Amazing Spider-man Peter Parker somehow ends up in a wrestling ring.  Is this based on a storyline in any of the Spider-man comics?

Comment: I thought it was an artifact. Spider-man and the Ring of Wrestling. Adds + 2 to melee and +1 to dodge.

Comment: @Zikato Spiderman's ring of wrestling (DnD ver.): gives +8 to grapple checks, allows you to ignore the reach of the opponent

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Indeed, this goes all the way back to 1962 and the the first-ever Spider-man story, *Amazing Fantasy* 15. From [comicbookresources.com](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=39377):

> Peter decides to test out his newfound powers by taking part in an amateur wrestling competition, donning a mask just in case he loses. Peter quickly beats pro wrestler Crusher Hogan and wins the competition prize money. A TV producer (later said to be a TV agent named Max Schiffman) witnesses the event and convinces Peter to perform on late night TV. He suggests Peter keep the "mask angle" since a secret identity is "great showmanship."
>
> *[...]*
>
> Minutes after his television debut as the "Amazing" Spider-Man, the web-spinner sees and ignores a thief that runs past him and escapes the building. When a security guard asks why Spidey didn't trip or grab the guy, the teenager displays newfound arrogance by proclaiming that he is no longer concerned with anyone but himself. Catching criminals isn't what he's paid to do.
>
> *[...]*
>
> For days (or weeks), Spider-Man continues to impress studio audiences and play to packed rooms. But one night, Peter finds police at the Parker home. They explain his Uncle Ben surprised a burglar who then shot and killed him. The burglar got away but police have cornered him at the old Acme warehouse at the waterfront. Enraged, Peter dons his Spider-Man outfit and confronts the burglar directly. After knocking the killer out, Peter sees his face and realizes in horror that it's the same thief from the studio. Guilt-ridden that he could have prevented his uncle's death if he hadn't been selfish, Peter realizes that "with great power there must also come -- great responsibility."

The movie adaptations tend to leave out the middle section, where he becomes a TV personality, likely in the interests of time. I've included scans of a handful of pages below (note that I did omit some of the in-between pages).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're officially the Fastest Gun In The West. :)

Comment: The webbing under his arms reminds me of a flying squirrel. I'm glad they cut that part of the costume.

Comment: @Ixrec the panel that shows the webbing under his arms just might inspire another question.

Comment: I miss the webbing under the arms

Comment: Holy macaroni. That's so completely different from the movie version I almost feel tempted to read the original comic.

Comment: @Mindwin Some of them are classics only because they were first, not necessarily good but I see your point :).

Comment: @Mindwin I am absolutely not saying that this particular comic is bad or anything, I'd certainly love to read the old issues myself (even though they do feel like they aged a lot, at least from those strips). Rather I was musing on how I've encountered various things in my life that were considered classics but they didn't live to the expectations, at least to my expectations. I had this with the movie "Nosferatu" which is a classic one but, beyond the titular, terrific role, was pretty mediocre even when compared to some other movies of the same decade.

Comment: @Maurycy Please keep extended discussion out of comments; take it to chat instead

Comment: @Mindwin See above; please take extended discussion to chat

Answer (score 18):

Jason Baker *just* beat me to the punch, but since I already got all the pictures ready, I'll add them here to supplement Jason's answer.

In the comics, as in the movies, one of the first things Peter Parker does after acquiring his superpowers is to wrestle "Crusher Hogan" for a cash prize.  This takes place in *Amazing Fantasy #15*.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Aaaaaaaand he beat me to the punch again with the pictures.  Dammit.

Comment: I guess this would be a pity upvote, but surely the slower gun deserves at least 20 fake internet points.

Comment: @WadCheber I'll definitely give you a +1 on this but since Jason beat you to it he will get the accept.

Comment: @Whovian4Life - That's fine.  He beat me fair and square.

Comment: This is why it's generally a good idea to go ahead and submit your answer, and then go back and edit in the visual aids or further elaboration.